# How do I enable SSL on SQL server express?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

that is possible?, and then how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the step by step guide from [Encrypting Connections to SQL Server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189067.aspx)